# AWS EC2 FTP port 21 not opened on my instance but allowed in security groups

Tags: linux, security, ftp, port, amazon-web-services

I try to launch a node js application on a ec2 instance. I authorize the port range in my security group:

[image: ec2 security group]

I stop the instance totally and restart it just to be sure.

But if I launch the command

```
netstat -ntlp / netstat -nulp
```

I have no local address with port 21, and if i launch the serveur, I got :

```
rejection Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:21
```

How can I enable access ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple, to launch process on any other port than 80, we have to launch it as root or they will be blocked